# How to get the valid part of a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test if a user string is "ok so far", in that it might not be valid as a whole but it is a subset of a valid one.

I have a regex say ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]$
such that "1234-1234-5678-5678" is valid

"1234-12" or even "1"  does not match pattern but its a valid subset of a valid format, in other words the input is ok so far.

is there a neat way of doing this without making many many regexes,    its friday.

Comment: so 1234-12 is valid or not?

Comment: Consider e.g. `'AAAAAc'.match(/A+b|c/)`. Is `AAAAA` a "valid subset", in your terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood well your problem, but I think you want to have something like this:

```
^([0-9]{4}-){1,3}[0-9]{1,4}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/HJaUeV/1/)**

This will match set of 4 digits and can have the last set from 1 to 4 digits

[image]

You can also shorten your regex with:

```
^(\d{4}-){1,3}\d{1,4}$
```

Comment: I like this one... But to cover all bases you could change it to `{0,3}`

Comment: There is another issue in that it won't match `1234-` where there is  a dangling dash, unless it's changed to `{0,4}` Over all though, this is the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use one final regex for validation of the form you currently have, and a on the fly regex for the user input being valid for each subset.

My idea would be to have ([0-9]{1,4}-)+

Comment: but that would make "1-2" valid and it isnt

Answer (score 0):

For your case this will check as one types:

```
/^(\d(\d(\d(\d(-(\d(\d(\d(\d(-(\d(\d(\d(\d(-(\d)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match key for key as you type, although it is a little cumbersome.

```
^([0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,4}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,4})$
```

[Here is a live example](https://regex101.com/r/gXVy6A/2)